# jQuery menu with (onclick) "selected item" image src changing

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build a menu in jquery with a hover and selected state...

On hover image is replaced with highlighted version and I also need a selected state for when I click a menu item (image replaced to a selected version).

The problem I have is when I click the another menu item I want to turn off any other selected menu items and return them to their original src before selecting the new menu item.

Here is my attempt... :\

```
  $("#profile_menu ul li").click(function(){                                            
            $(this).addClass("menu_selected")                      
            var img = $(this).children().children(".menu_icon").attr("src")
            var allimgs = $(".menu_icon").attr("src")
            var selected_state = img.replace(".png","_click.png")
            var normalstate = allimgs.replace("_click.png",".png")
            $(".menu_icon").attr("src",normal_state)
            $(this).children().children(".menu_icon").attr("src",selected_state)
        })
```

**The problem is when I click the next item it changes all of the menu images to the same image...**

Thanks in advance,

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
$(".menu_icon").attr("src")
```

will get the image URL of the **first** matched element. You are then setting this URL for all other images, making all the images the same.

Better: Set the new attribute by passing a function to `.attr()`:

```
$(".menu_icon").attr("src", function(i, src) {
    return src.replace("_click.png",".png");
});
```

You can do this for the selected image too, which would result in this code:

```
$("#profile_menu ul li").click(function() {
    $(this)
     .addClass("menu_selected")
     .find('.menu_icon').attr('src', function(i, src) {
         return src.replace(".png","_click.png");
     });
    $(".menu_icon").attr("src", function(i, src) {
        return src.replace("_click.png",".png");
    });
    // you might also need
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('menu_selected');
});
```

---

Don't forget semicolons `;` at the end a statement!